# how to generate documentations with haddock?

Tags: haskell, documentation, haddock

The project I am using does not have docs on Stackage (they're out of date). Here is the original one which is on verson 0.3

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflex-dom-0.3/docs/Reflex-Dom-Widget-Basic.html

I was told I could generate docs with haddock.  I have the source code on my computer (using `git clone`) version 0.4

The [haddock](https://www.haskell.org/haddock/doc/html/index.html) web page was way too advanced.

For the beginner, once I am in my directory, how do I generate docs?

---

Thanks to one of the answer I made come progress, but here is an error message:

```
src/Reflex/Dom/Xhr.hs:154:0:
     error: missing binary operator before token "("
     #if MIN_VERSION_aeson(1,0,0)
     ^
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the problem is. You do not know how to generate the documentation as webpages? Or you have a question how to install it? Or you have a question about a specific feature in haddock?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem after I `git clone` what do I type into the shell to generate documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have installed `haddock`, you can run it as follows:

```sh
haddock --html -o <haddock-folder> <list-of-haskell-files>
```

So for instance:

```sh
haddock --html -o the_documentation *.hs
```

will generate the documentation of all the Haskell files in that directory (not any subdirectories) in a directory named `the_documentation`.

Some shells allow `**.hs` to look for **all** `.hs` files (subdirectories included). So you might try:

```sh
haddock --html -o the_documentation **.hs
```

If the shell does not suport that, you can of course use a combination of `find` and `xargs`, like:

```sh
find -iname '*.hs' | xargs haddock --html -o the_documentation
```

Here `find` will generate a list of all files that end with `.hs`, and `xargs` will write all these files as parameters to `haddock --html ...`.

Comment: yes I was about to say... how my Haskell files are buried in `*.hs` files at various depths. `find . -name "*.hs"` oh you got tat!

Comment: can you tell `haddock` to skip files where haddock doesn't work?

Comment: @johnmangual: I never encountered this error before. It looks like haddock is having problems with a "macro".

Comment: @johnmangual: does adding `--optghc='-cpp'` solves the issue?

Answer (score 5):

`cabal haddock` or `stack haddock`.

Comment: where are the documentations saved?

Comment: @johnmangual At least for `stack haddock`, stack will tell you where the documentation is saved after you run `stack haddock`.